# submitting form in auto it

Tags: html, autocomplete, automation, autoit

The problem is :
I have form in html which contain :-

`"two text-box"` and `" bottom to submit"`

What I want is :
Make the script in automatically add some text and submit form without opening an internet explorer window (just the script).

I tried to implement a get and post, but it failed

```
#include<ie.au3>
$oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
$oHTTP.Open("GET", "http://localhost/2.html", False)
_IELinkClickByText( $oHTTP , "submit")
$oHTTP.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with WinHttp.au3 - https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/84133-winhttp-functions/
Check on _WinHttpSimpleFormFill which fills a form and then submits

Answer (score 0):

Functions with "_IE" prefix is not used for WinHttp object. So, you cannot call the **_IELinkClickByText** function.

Example using IE UDF to submit a form:

```
#include <IE.au3>
Local $oIE = _IECreate('http://localhost/2.html')
Local $oForm = _IEFormGetCollection($oIE, 0)
_IEFormSubmit($oForm)
```

But if you want to use WinHttp, you should use the **POST** method instead of **GET**.